# How to make an isomorphic JavaScript app with Mithril JS

Tags: mithril.js

I'd like to be able to render javascript templates using the Mithril JS framework on the server for SEO and first load purposes and have them run in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this blog post:
https://gist.github.com/StephanHoyer/bddccd9e159828867d2a

And this example repo:
https://github.com/StephanHoyer/mithril-isomorphic-example

to run the demo, simply

```
Clone the repo
cd into it
run npm install
run node server
```

Answer (score 0):

Give my new framework (https://github.com/ezramorse/mens) a whirl for an out of box solution

```
npm install mens
node node_modules/mens/example/server.js
```

Or just require('mens') from the root and start from scratch!